# Error calling non-static method

Tags: c#, timer, non-static

I have this timer

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
aTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimerMethod);
aTimer.Interval = 5000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

But when I call this method in timer code,

```
private void OnTimerMethod(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("text");
}
```

I get this error message

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

How can I fix this ?

Update :
I see I'm doing wrong but how can I achieve doing this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's not nearly enough **context** to give you a reasonable answer.  For starters, how are you calling the method `OnTimerMethod`?  Show some code around that.  We don't need everything, but we do need more than you've posted so far.

Comment: In most web programming, the response context will be long gone by the time that something like a timer callback happens. You can't just write to a web response from arbitrary threads at arbitrary times. What is it you're actually trying to **do** here? I suspect this is a X/Y problem. You're asking us about Y, but until we understand what you're actually trying to *achieve* (the X), helping you solve Y is probably just going to mislead you further. Like someone complaining that they can't hammer their screws (not nails) in very easily, so us handing you a bigger hammer.

Comment: @Tim , I'm calling already in code, you can search, this method is being called every 5 seconds, you may missed it.

Comment: I dont see any code explicitly calling the method. This is an indeed an XY problem, I suggest you write whatever you really need, and not trying to slowly feed the data to a web client, which is ok but not in direct web call.

Comment: @AgentFire it is a timer event callback via a delegate instance; that much isn't the issue; of course it can't possibly hope to append to a web response

Comment: Comments summary. What functionality are you trying to create? - dont say how you think you should code it

Comment: To be very explicit: if your intention is to drip feed text onto an in progress web-response, *this isn't going to work*; that isn't how you do page updates. To achieve this, you're going to need either ajax from the client, or something like web-sockets.

Comment: @pm100 , I'm trying to run the call a Response.Write or Response.Redirect when the method called by timer.

Comment: @Synthman that's not what he asked. He is asking why are you doing it.

Comment: nope - thats how you think you should code it. What are you actually trying to do? "I am trying to animate a gif on the screen","I am streamina video" ,....

Comment: sorry, I'm trying to make a reminder, so I'll pop some messages at the detected time

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to make a reminder, so I'll pop some messages at the detected time

You cannot do this by simply writing extra data to a completed response context. The http life cycle *doesn't allow for this*, at least not in http 1.*. Instead, you would need to (one of):

- move all the timer code to the client and worry about it in javascript
- run ajax from the client and poll the server periodically
- establish a web-socket connection from the client to the server; this allows the server to push messages to the client without requiring a request, but requires an established and active TCP connection between client and server, and requires a different programming model for the web-socket server

Your best bet for a reminder is probably just the first one.

Comment: since OP is running on IIS i suggest signalr web socket implementation